# How to login/enter in kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I have kubernetes pods running as shown in command *"kubectl get all -A*" :

[image]

and same pods are shown in command *"kubectl get pod -A"* :
[image]

I want to enter/login to any of these pod (all are in Running state). How can I do that please let me know the command?

Comment: you cannot login to a pod. it is not a process. it is a kind of 'environment'. it doesn't have port numbers. only IP. but as mentioned by others, you can exec binaries present on the node, which run as a container.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Kubernetes Pods are not *Virtual Machines*, so not something you typically can "log in" to.

But you might be able to *execute a command* in a container. e.g. with:

```
kubectl exec <pod-name> -- <command>
```

Note that your container need to contain the binary for `<command>`, otherwise this will fail.

See also [Getting a shell to a container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/).

Comment: Just like we login to docker container by "docker attach container_name" and then we can execute commands inside the container, I thought we might can into kubernetes pods as well.

Comment: yes you can ```kubectl exec <pod-name>  -it -- /bin/sh ```

Comment: I was able to login to pod with command: 
kubectl exec <pod_name> -n <pod_namespace> -it  /bin/sh

Answer (score 29):

In addition to Jonas' answer above;
If you have more than one namespace, you need to specify the namespace your pod is currently using i.e `kubectl exec -n <name space here> <pod-name>  -it -- /bin/sh`

After successfully accessing your pod, you can go ahead and navigate through your container.

Comment: If your pod has many containers, you can do: `kubectl exec -n <NAMESPACE> <POD_NAME> --container <CONTAINER_NAME> -it -- /bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

Using this command you can access the container inside pod

kubectl exec -it < your pod name which you want to access> -- /bin/bash