# How do I login to a kubernetes pod and edit a yaml file inside it using a python script?

Tags: python, kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

I can login to a pod using

```
kubectl exec <pod-name> -- <command>
```

as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67550782/how-to-login-enter-in-kubernetes-pod).

But I want to achieve this using a python script, and then I wish to use the same python script to edit the yaml file inside that pod.

How can I do this? I'm new to both python and kubernetes so please help me get started.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the official Kubernetes client for Python
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, look into Kubernetes client libraries - since you're using python, that one: https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python . Keeping in mind [exec/attach support is problematic](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python#why-execattach-calls-doesnt-work).

Copying files into a container, you have the following thread on SO: [Copy file from pod to host by using kubernetes python client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59703610/copy-file-from-pod-to-host-by-using-kubernetes-python-client) . I'm not sure in-container direct edition would be easy / better pull your existing configuration if needed, then overwrite it.

Also consider using a ConfigMap, configuring your workload. Then, you could either trigger a restart of your Pods, when that configuration is changed, or look into something better ... Prometheus ships with the prometheus config reloader: a sidecar, that would watch for changes to some ConfigMaps, installs the last copy on a volume that would be shared with your main application, then send some signal instructing that application to re-read its configuration...